# AKMIDI - Different behaviour - virtual midi

Tags: midi, audiokit

I have the following situation: In my app I have created virtual MIDI ports, as explained in some examples on the Audiokit page.
I use midi in order to trigger AKMIDISampler and AKMIDISampler loads .aupresets for percusive instruments. I create the .aupresets in the AULAB so that the NOTE OFF should be ignored.
So the samples can fade out and will not be cut off when the next hit comes.
It works as expected with my MIDI Keyboard and some other hardware MIDI controller. MIDI NOTE OFF is ignored, previous sound can fade out and the sounds overlap fine. But when I load my App in AudioBus and trigger it over virtual MIDI with a Sequencer, every new sample always cuts off the previous one. That sounds very unnatural and should be changed.

Where is the difference between virtual MIDI and not virtual? What am I doing wrong and how to get the same behaviour on both levels? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

```
//open midi ports        

let midi = AudioKit.midi
    midi.createVirtualPorts()
    midi.openInput(name: "Session 1")
    midi.addListener(self)






//Play Sampler 

    func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
    do {
         try self.myMIDISampler.play(noteNumber: myNote, velocity: velocity, channel: myMIDIChannel)
        } catch {
                    AKLog("Can't play the file, error:\(error)")
                 }
    }
```

It should have the same results on virtual midi and hardware midi commands. 
In principle I think I need a way to ignore / filter midi note off at all levels. 
That could also be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@user3491466,

Without seeing your entire Xcode project and the .aupreset that you've saved from AU Lab, could you try increasing the layer's Release Time in the parameters menu, so that the samples continue to play out and not get cut off?

[image: Image of AU Lab preset parameters]

Please let me know if this helps at all. Be sure to also check out the Audiobus SDK and associated classes that are in the AudioKit Synth One open source project. That way, you can see if there's anything that's set differently.

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKitSynthOne

Comment: Hi Mark and thanks for your answer! I just tried releasing time to 60, but unfortunately it's the same again. If I play on midi keyboard then it is ok if play via virtual port from another app, such as MIDI Wrench or Aftertouch, then when I first start loudly with e.g. velocity 120 and then velocity 10, the first tone is cut off, despite a change in the release time. How can it be that the results are different? MIDI command should be MIDI command ... Maybe it's a bug?